# Problem loading cram_plan_library

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Fuerte on Ubuntu10.04X64, cram_highlevel is the latest clone from Github. It seems cram_plan_library uses some symbols which is not defined in cl_tf yet?

```
; compiling file "/home/s117219/ros/fuerte_workspace/stable_stacks/cram_highlevel/cram_plan_library/src/at-location.lisp" (written 14 NOV 2012 01:44:02 PM):
; compiling (IN-PACKAGE :PLAN-LIB)
; compiling (DEFVAR *AT-LOCATION-LOCK* ...)
; compiling (DEFCONSTANT +AT-LOCATION-RETRY-COUNT+ ...)
; compiling (CRAM-PROJECTION:DEFINE-SPECIAL-PROJECTION-VARIABLE *AT-LOCATION-LOCK* ...)
; compiling (DEFUN LOCATION-DESIGNATOR-REACHED ...)
; compiling (DEFMACRO WITH-EQUATE-FLUENT ...)
;
; compilation aborted because of fatal error:
;   SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-PACKAGE-ERROR at 3626 (line 75, column 45) on #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM
;                                                                        for "file /home/s117219/ros/fuerte_workspace/stable_stacks/cram_highlevel/cram_plan_library/src/at-location.lisp"
;                                                                        {10044AC5E1}>:
;     Symbol "WITH-TRANSFORMS-CHANGED-CALLBACK" not found in the CL-TF package.
;   
; compilation aborted after 0:00:00.057
WARNING:
   COMPILE-FILE warned while performing #<COMPILE-OP NIL {1003BAB741}> on
   #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "cram-plan-library" "src" "at-location">.
; 
; compilation unit aborted
;   caught 2 fatal ERROR conditions
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48398/problem-loading-cram_plan_library/) by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2012-11-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on 2012-11-15**:
Thanks again @Lorenz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some refactoring of `AT-LOCATION`, cram_plan_library now needs the most recent development version of cl_tf. You need to check out the stack `roslisp_common` using svn from the following url: https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/roslisp_common/trunk

For instance, you can use the following rosinstall file:

```
-svn:
    local-name: roslisp_common
    uri: 'https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/roslisp_common/trunk'
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1